# Writing a Database Query to a file

Tags: php

I am trying to write a Database Query to a file, But am just wondering how I get the SQL Data to be input into the file.

It is currently outputting nothing to the .txt file at all. I suspect its something to do with the while loop and am questioning whether it needs to be there or not.

My code is :

```
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($name,$link);

$query = "SELECT gamename, username, MAX(thescore)
          FROM game_scores
          GROUP BY gamename, username
          ORDER BY gamename, thescore DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $scoredata = $row;
}


//save file
$handle = fopen('scores/games-backup'.'.txt','w+');
fwrite($handle,$scoredate);
fclose($handle);

echo "Success";
 }
```

Any help on writing the SQL Results to this text file would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` is an array, you will need to make it a string before you can write it to a file, you can use `implode()`.

$scoredata is also being overwritten in each loop, maybe use $scoredata[] instead

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $scoredata[] = implode("; ", $row);
}
```

This will make `$scoredata` an array also, so you will need to convert that to a string too!

```
$handle = fopen('scores/games-backup'.'.txt','w+');
fwrite($handle,implode("\r\n", $scoredata));
fclose($handle);
```

This should print each database row on a new line in the file.

EDIT: This will just be a text file, formatted as text, not that great for a backup file. You will need to structure the text into an SQL format to make it useful..

Comment: Thanks @Jleagle Getting an error on that fwrite line : Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Bad arguments on line 27

Comment: Because you have one called $scoredata and one called $scoredate

Comment: Brilliant thanks @Jleagle its not a back up file as such. Its going to be a snapshot of game scores ran as a cron job at a specific time of day.

Comment: You can replace `implode("; ", $row)` with `$row['col1'].'; '.$row['col2']` etc to make it more specific

Answer (score 2):

`$row` is not a string, you have to make it a string before you can put it into a file.
And you have to change `$scoredata` to `$scoredata[]` because, it is now being overwritten continiously.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like :

```
$handle = fopen('scores/games-backup'.'.txt','w+');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  fputs($handle, join(';', $row)."\n");
}

fclose($handle);
```

$row is an array, you must join it (or access the elements )

Answer (score 1):

You can use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function with second parameter set true.

```
$str = print_r($row, true);    
fwrite($handle,implode("\r\n", $str));
```

Or you can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array

```
$str = serialize($row);
fwrite($handle,implode("\r\n", $str));
```